# How to develop an IMAP Server Interface, are there libraries available?

Tags: java

I need to develop a Message Storage Server using IMAP. Is there any Java API/library that allows me to do this?

I know there are a few IMAP Servers available like Apache James or Dwarf, but i don't want a full email product, I want to be able to change what the server does uppon receiving IMAP commands (Folder management, etc..).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library. It belongs to the standard java mail api.

https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html